# Is it possible to use BITAND operator in BigQuery with Non Integer values?

Tags: google-bigquery, bitwise-and

I am using BITAND (&) operator in BigQuery

```
select (cast val as INT64) & pow(2,63) = pow(2,63)
```

The value for the field Val and pow(2,63) is exceeding the maximum value of integer and hence BITAND is not working.

I typecasted it to other data types but they are not working with BITAND operator

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting and processing, casting both values to int64. Also, note that Bitwise and operator throws an error if X and Y are bytes of different lengths.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(val AS INT64) AS val,
    CAST(POW(2, 63) AS INT64) AS bitmask
  FROM
    WhateverTable)
SELECT
  val,
  bitmask,
  IF(val & bitmask = bitmask, TRUE, FALSE) AS result
FROM
  CTE;
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#bitwise_operators

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am still getting Integer out of Range error as we do cast(val as INT64) or cast(pow(2,63) as INT64).

Comment: then can you try with other long integer datatypes such as numeric? the limit is 2^63 i believe

Comment: Limit is 9 223 372 000 000 000 000. (which is 2^63)